# Run script on Startup on openSUSE

Tags: linux, bash, cron, opensuse

**Task**: Run chromium on startup on openSUSE

**So far:**

First I don't know what path to take, it's possible with Cron or from rc.local. I don't know which opinion is the best

**Cron:**

Figured out that it's not a very good idea

**rc.local**

So I have this script:

```
Fri Aug 11; 06:10:38; marton;/etc/init.d ;  $  cat /etc/init.d/chrom_start.sh 
#!/bin/bash
/usr/lib64/chromium/chromium
exit 0
```

I have permissions for the file:

```
Fri Aug 11; 06:11:09; marton;/etc/init.d ;  $  ls -l /etc/init.d/chrom_start.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root 48 Aug 11 06:10 /etc/init.d/chrom_start.sh
```

openSUSE doesn't have update-rc.d

```
Fri Aug 11; 06:12:48; marton;/etc/init.d ;  $  update-rc.d
If 'update-rc.d' is not a typo you can use command-not-found to lookup the package that contains it, like this:
    cnf update-rc.d
```

I can't seem to find the example:

```
Fri Aug 11; 06:13:18; marton;/etc/init.d ;  $  cat /etc/init.d/skeleton
cat: /etc/init.d/skeleton: No such file or directory
```

Somewhere I found that I have to use install job but it does not exist

```
Fri Aug 11; 06:20:35; marton;/etc/init.d ;  $  %install
bash: fg: %install: no such job
```

So, if everything is alright, I just have to find a way to set the daemon to run on startup, what do I do next, considering that I don't have this skeleton file and these install job does not exist?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it'll be of help on OpenSUSE, but here is a thread about "how to autostart Chromium" :

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38515/auto-start-chromium-on-raspbian-jessie-11-2015

Answer (score 0):

This may help too.

If you are using bash (it is the most probable scenario) you could edit your `.bash_profile` file, or `.bash_login` (both should be in your user's home directory).

You need to add at the end your chromium's path like:

```
/usr/bin/chromium&
```

the final `&` is to make it run as a background process. If you want to apply this change for every user you can edit your .bash_login file on `/etc/skel`

Hope it helps,

ps. here is an url that may help a bit.

http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_01.html